Marriage in Manusmriti
So I recall reading in Manusmriti that a man may marry a second time once his first wife dies, but wouldn't that be rare due to the age of marriage?

What are you asking for? A confirmation that there's such a line, or a resolution of the apparent contradiction?

@CDR a resolution to apparent contradiction or rather probability.
